# LinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(int) not working in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to set a custom colour to my linear layout in code using android `Pallete`.

Code is given below:

```
public void changeColour(Pallete palette){
   v = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_info, null);
   contactInfo = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_layout);
   contactInfo.setBackgroundColor(palette.getDarkMutedSwatch().getBodyTextColor());
}
```

I have also tried to make `ColorDrawable` first and then using it to set background like this .

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(palette.getDarkMutedSwatch().getBodyTextColor());
contactInfo.setBackground(cd);
```

But even this doesn't work. `contactInfo` is an element of a `ListView`.

XML for list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/contact_layout"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2.6"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:text="User name"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/check" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is Pallete?  Do you mean android.support.v7.graphics.Palette?

Comment: yes android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;

Comment: Have you tried using setBackgroundColor instead of setBackground?

Comment: yes i have basically in the given function i used backgroundcolor . but even this isn't working .

Comment: What is the vaue of `palette.getDarkMutedSwatch().getBodyTextColor()`?

Comment: It returns an integer of a color .

Comment: Could you post the layout XML file, if you're generating it dynamically?

Comment: try `contactInfo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` and you will see that it just works, probably `palette.getDarkMutedSwatch().getBodyTextColor()` returns not what you want

Comment: I did try that and it doesn't work . 
Please also see that contactInfo is an element of listview .

Comment: What is the current value of `getBodyTextColor()`?

Comment: When you say listView I am sure you mean an element of listItem , can you share the listItem xml

Comment: @gaurav4sarma i have edited my question and posted code of list item above

Comment: @KNeerajLal value is -2013265921

Comment: Did you try to get colors from other methods of swatch, just to test color and if it is properly applied?

Comment: @NightFury yes i did try to apply Color.BLUE and it didn't work

Comment: @pskink  I am sorry i did not understand your question . Please elaborate

Comment: v.findViewById(R.id.contact_layout);
contact_layout is not present in the layout of this activity in which i am writing code . That is why i had to inflate contact_info .

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem . I changed color of layout in the array adapter and it changed . Solution is given below .

```
 public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       View view = convertView;
       view.findViewById(R.id.contact_layout).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
```

So by passing the color to array adapter through an array of objects i was able to solve my problem .